# Can not validate the server SSL certificate

Tags: c, openssl, ssl-certificate, pem

I'm trying to make a client connect to some servers via https, using openssl library.

The call stack is something like this:

```
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method());
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "file_with_trusted_certificates", NULL);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
BIO *bio = BIO_new_socket(...);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);

SSL_connect(ssl);

SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
```

I have 2 servers with ssl certificates, which I have extracted using openssl tool and put into "file_with_trusted_certificates" file:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server_url:443
```

The problem is the following: one server is validated (though if not using file_with_trusted_certificates it fails with error 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain), but the check of the second server always fails with error 20: unable to get local issuer certificate. When passing

```
"-CAfile file_with_trusted_certificates"
```

to openssl tool, both servers get validated.

What I am doing wrong, why doesn't the second server also get validated?

The servers have different ciphers, and the one that succeeds has secure renegotiation enabled.

**EDIT:**

The C client runs on a arm device, which has libssl v0.9.8. The openssl tool run on the embedded device yields the same result as the C application: error 20 for first server and OK for the other. Using a linux environment, the openssl tool yield OK for both server, but then, maybe the version of the C application would do the same.

Comment: two server had the same openssl version?

Comment: @vathek, it appears that the protocol used is TLSv1, I also tried setting SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE flag, but to no avail

Comment: import the second certificate into file_with_trusted_certificates returns some warning?

Comment: @vathek, I generated file_with_trusted_certificates in different ways (browser export, openssl tool), it just contains multiple pem certificates encoded in base64, I never got any warnings and I checked that the certificates were not corrupted using some online tool.

Comment: You mean to say with s_client, both servers yield verify code 0 (OK) but with you C code, one is OK but another error 20?

Comment: @Prabhu, yes, although the tests with s_client were performed on a linux machine, while the C code runs on an arm device, with the same file_with_trusted_certificates

Comment: @gg.kaspersky. I just tried with program on Linux. Worked fine. Is the certificate chain same across server? Do they differ in some way

Comment: @Prabhu, they are 2 different servers, with 2 different certificate chains. I have obtained the ca certificates with s_client tool and online tool

Comment: @gg.kaspersky might be obvious . Still checking. What does Openssl verify command yield against two Certs and CA file?

Comment: What are the server's DNS names or addresses? If you don't show us the certificates and don't provide the server's DNS name or address, then we can't help.

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server_url:443` is effectively different than `SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method());`. Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on for a way you could do it to provide a firmer security posture.

Comment: @jww, I have made an edit to the question, maybe that could help

Answer (score 0):

After some trial-error, I managed to find the problem.

I needed to add the certificate of the issuer of the root certificate in the chain in "file_with_trusted_certificates" file, but I added just the root certificate in the chain:

```
Common name: Baltimore CyberTrust Root -> I added this
Issuer: GTE CyberTrust Global Root -> I needed to add the certificate of this
```

Interestingly, it was working for the other server because the root certificate in the chain was self-signed and authorized:

```
Common name: AddTrust External CA Root
Issuer: AddTrust External CA Root
```